# Laravel 5 - returns array, but no array[key]

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have an array that I return from my controller to my view.
If I enter the following:

```
{{ $subpage["name"] }}
```

Laravel throws an error (undefinded index: name).
However, when I use:

```
{{ $subpage }}
```

I get this result:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Additional Information","category":"General","link":"additionalinfo","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]
```

So I really don't see what I'm doing wrong?

Framework: Laravel 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an object, in an array, you can notice that since you have curly braces (`{}`) around your variables.

You will need to use `$subpage[0]->name` to access the value just like you would in a controller, to access some model's object.

Comment: that did the trick!, Thanks ...
I already upvoted the answer, I'll mark it as the correct one as soon as possible ...